# Objective c - Correct way to release an UIVIewController

Tags: objective-c, ios4, memory

I'm having problems releasing `UIView` controller, this is my code.
When I press a button, I put a View on the screen in front of everything:

```
   viewT = [[PersonalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PersonalViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
//In this moment the retainCount is 1
[[AppDelegate appDelegate].window  insertSubview:viewT.view aboveSubview:[AppDelegate appDelegate].dockController.view];
[viewT release];
//Now the retain count is 3!

//... After some code, when the user press another button, I want to release the view
 [viewT.view removeFromSuperview];
//After this line, the object stills there, with a retain of 2.
```

So something it's happening and I don't understand. I've been reading guides about memory and I've never had this doubt before, what am I doing wrong? How can I completely release `viewT`???

Comment: Have you tried with autorelease?

Comment: Thanks, it could be the solution, but can I be sure that the view is not going to be released until I remove it from superview?

Comment: This is why you aren't supposed to use `retainCount`. Your code is fine; you've released an object you created. That's all that matters.

Comment: If my code it's fine, why dealloc in viewT it's never been called? Next time I press the button Im going to alloc another PersonalViewController and the preovious one it's not released at all

Comment: The only thing that happens when you use retainCount for debugging purposes is that you end up here asking bewildered questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You own any object you create when

> You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”,
>   “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or
>   mutableCopy).

- When you no longer need it, you must relinquish ownership of an
  object you own

> You relinquish ownership of an object by sending it a release message
>   or an autorelease message. In Cocoa terminology, relinquishing
>   ownership of an object is therefore typically referred to as
>   “releasing” an object.

- You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own

> This is just corollary of the previous policy rules, stated
>   explicitly.

[Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)

So, you need only one line of code

```
[viewT release];
```

Comment: Also about `retainCount`: _This method is typically of no value in debugging memory management issues. Because any number of framework objects may have retained an object in order to hold references to it, while at the same time autorelease pools may be holding any number of deferred releases on an object, it is very unlikely that you can get useful information from this method._

Comment: I meant, why it's never called?

Comment: I know, and it's suppose to happen when I release the object, isn't it?

Comment: No. `release` decrease reference counts. But something can hold your object (such an array with objects) and reference count != 0. You create an object with 'alloc', 'new', 'copy', 'retain' - you should release this object. That's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a retain cycle.  Do any of the objects in your nib have an outlet connected to File's Owner?  Is that outlet declared `retain`?  (Or `strong` if you're using ARC, which you're not.)  Change the outlet to `assign` (or `weak` if using ARC).